# How to run/start .jar file stored in Eclipse Library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a file called FakeSMTP-2.0.jar, which is stored in my project library on Eclipse. It is used to act as an SMTP server, allowing me to 'send' emails. To use it, I need to run the file, choose a folder to save the emails to, and click a button to 'start' the server.

Currently, I open the file manually in my computer (from File Explorer) first, and on running the code, it works perfectly fine. However, as the project will be shared with others, I want to make it such that when the program runs, the .jar file in the library will run as well.

Is there a certain code/settings that I can use to do this?